# Using /data and /execute to find the nearest player's selected item's enchantments? (1.16 snapshots)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

### Very long post ahead.

I'll place a tl;dr at the bottom for those who want/need.

I'm attempting to create a "chunk buster" TNT bomb that will blow up a 16x16x16 area, starting from the block of TNT as the upper north-west corner, dropping all the items. Now, this works absolutely fine, but it's boring since everyone else has done something similar--so I want to go a step ahead and detect the player who placed the TNT's first pickaxe enchantment (eg. Fortune on a pickaxe) and mess with things from there.

For now, here are the basic working commands, pre-enchantment idea. First, in a repeating, always active command block I scan for a TNT block with 5 ticks left sitting on chiseled polished blackstone;

```
execute as @e[type=tnt,nbt={Fuse:5s}] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chiseled_polished_blackstone run fill ~ ~ ~ ~15 ~-15 ~15 air destroy
```

Then, using a conditional, always active, chain command block, I kill it before it can actually explode;

```
kill @e[type=tnt,nbt={Fuse:5s}]
```

With Fortune as an example, I want to be able to double, triple, or quadruple block drop amounts accordingly--and yes, I'm aware that some computers can't necessarily handle all of that. Another idea was Mending, where if you had it on your item, all the experience gained from using the "chunk buster" would go straight to the item.

Here's the issue; using `/data get` I know the path to a player's selected item is `SelectedItem`, and to go to the first enchantment would be `SelectedItem.tags.Enchantments[0]`. The problem is that I can't simply output `Enchantments[0].id` to a scoreboard or whatever for use, since scoreboards etc. only support numerical values. This means that I can't do anything to store what that value actually is in order to apply it anywhere or use it for anything.

I attempted, at first for Mending, to go "the hard route" and simply use `if entity @e[...,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:'mending',lvl:1}]}}}]` to set--if it was found--an "enchID" dummy scoreboard to "1" for that player. I found, however, that this was not working at all. Below are the commands I tried to accomplish this;

First, replacing the original kill block, I placed in a chain, always active, conditional block with the following;

```
execute as @e[type=tnt,nbt={Fuse:5s}] at @s if entity @e[type=player,limit=1,sort=nearest,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:mending,lvl:1}]}}}] run scoreboard players set @e[type=player,limit=1,sort=nearest] enchID 1
```

This should, if I'm correct;

- ...find a TNT block with 5 ticks left and execute as it,
- ...find the nearest player with an item that has the Mending enchantment on it,
- ...set that player's `enchID` score to 1.

Then, after that, in another similar block;

```
execute as @a[scores={enchID=1}] at @s run tp @e[type=minecraft:experience_orb] @s
```

...which should;

- ...execute as everyone with the score of 1,
- ...and teleport every experience orb entity to them.

However, after testing, it doesn't seem to be setting the scoreboard at all. I can't seem to figure out why--erasing `{tag:...}` and replacing it with `{id:diamond_pickaxe}` doesn't seem to make it work either. If this can't work, I myself don't know of any other viable options to find and use the info of what enchantments a player has.

### Tl;dr, I can't find a way to get and use a player's selected item enchantment, even through /data and through other workaround means of it.

Are there any other ways I'm forgetting about that can potentially solve this issue for me?

Comment: "Very long post"? I had to move the commands from some of my answers to Pastebin, because they didn't fit into the character limit. :D

Comment: Since your question just comes down to "this one command doesn't do what I expected", it would be better to reduce it to that. All the other commands in your setup seem to work, right?

Comment: It doesn't come down just to "this doesn't work the way I wanted" because that method isn't exactly what I wanted to begin with--it's just a temporary workaround that'll likely cause more issues for other enchantments later. Yes, however, the rest of the commands that actually do the mining all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

NBT matches have to be exact: `"minecraft:mending"`, not just `"mending"`.

Comment: I found that you're right in more ways than one, but that still prompts an issue on my part.  I want some enchantments to work regardless of level, but I'd still have to put in their level in multiple different command blocks for each level any given enchantment has, which goes down to my original question; is there any way to just grab the enchantment ID and go from there?

Comment: No, you don't have to enter the level. You can also copy it to somewhere else, like storage, using `data modify`, if you prefer that. But I don't think it allows you to do anything that you can't already do anyway.

Comment: I attempted to enter the full ID and it still wouldn't work without the level included. On that topic, though, how would I copy such a thing into storage in order to use it in a command like that? This is the issue I'm having--I see no readily available way to store/get the information and use it elsewhere.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/data#Storage